# How to set default time of ion-datetime?

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, time

I am trying to set the default time of this datetime picker to 0800. Any idea how i can do this?

```
<ion-label floating>Time: From</ion-label>
          <ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm" pickerFormat="HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="request.from" ></ion-datetime>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like :

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.myDate = "2017-08-08 11:22:00";
```

Comment: my displayFormat is "HH:mm" without the date

Comment: So i used this.request.from = "08:00"

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: since my format is HH:mm, i used this.request.from = "08:00" in ts file and it worked

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'll receive the wrong **date format** from the DB side. So, will change to the below formate. and it will work like other normal variables no extra settings or anything will be required for that.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Date format for `ion-datetime` must be like:

```
this.myDate = 2018-12-24T13:03:38.136Z;
```

So, make sure you are receiving valid date formate.